# getting error running selenium script.Not opening a session with chrome browing

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My tests were running fine . suddenly I am seeing this error . It opens multiple sessions but doesn't enter into the test . I used different versions of chromedriver but seeing the same error .below is the error I a seeing

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 18242
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1607528549.423][WARNING]: FromSockAddr failed on netmask
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Dec 09, 2020 7:42:31 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port 1070
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Comment: I have the latest version of browser which is 87.0.4280.88 and chromedriver which is  87.0.4280.88. I don't think version 88 is out for the chrome browser

Comment: I haven't upgraded my chrome browser long time. However official document says  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads it is rolled out. That's the reason I asked you to check version.

Comment: Chrome browser 88 is Beta version and it supports only Andriod and Windows . All out team is using 87 version and nobody is facing this issue

Comment: @VijayaSri Update the question with the complete error stacktrace and your code trials.

Comment: @DebanjanB I posted the complete error message in the question . I issue is when i run the test in my virtual machine . it opens the session ( chrome browser) and another session and another but it does not go into the test . It was working fine and suddenly seeing this issue . It gives multiple messages as I mentioned in my question details when ever a session is opened  and then the test hangs . I don't see any other log messages